# Change failover time for aws kcl

Tags: node.js, amazon-kinesis, failover, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kcl

AWS recommends to increase failover time for KCL (kinesis), if apps with connectivity issues.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/troubleshooting-consumers.html

But I can’t find how failover time can be changed.

I’m looking for (one or all):

- settings in AWS console
- settings for the node.js kcl package
- settings by Terraform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failover time is a configuration option for the Kinesis Client Library. It is not a property on the stream. As a result, you cannot change it in the AWS console.

Configuring AWS Kinesis Client library for Node.js is done using property files. I assume you already have a property file otherwise you wouldn't be able to start up your consumer application. What you need to do is add this to your property file:

```
# Fail over time in milliseconds.
failoverTimeMillis = 10000
```

See this sample property file provided by the library:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-nodejs/blob/master/samples/basic_sample/consumer/sample.properties#L38

Also see this documentation for more detail on how to change the property file: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-nodejs.html#kinesis-record-processor-initialization-nodejs